# At what levels do monsters get skill points?

Tags: dragon-quest-monsters-joker-2

At what level do you get skill points in *Dragon Quest Monsters: Joker 2*? I'm leveling monsters for synthesis and want to what the valuable breakpoints are as far as level.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [this](https://gamefaqs.gamespot.com/boards/933956-dragon-quest-monsters-joker/52952613) post:

> Levels 5, 8, 11, 15, 17, 21, 25, 26, 30, 35, 38, 39, 40 are when
> you'll get skill points (There's obviously more to be gained in later
> levels, but these are the ones you'll likely see most)